# In Tornado Can I update database name in request handler dynamically?

Tags: python, sqlite, tornado

Can I change database name defined in my Application class like below
or 
What is right approach to change database name dynamically in Tornado?

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
     def __init__(self):
        self.db = "test"
```

In one of my Request Handler using value from args

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, database):
        self.database = database
        self.db = "new_test"
```

Comment: It's just a property. Sure you can change it at any time.

Answer (score 1):

If by "dynamically" you mean you can modify it for different handlers, you can pass it to your [URLSpec](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.URLSpec):

```
from tornado.web import url

from myhandlers import MyHandler

urls_list = [
    url('/foo/bar', MyHandler, kwargs={'database': my_database}),
]

app = Application(urls_list)
```